# How to pass variable to match statement if not part of sequence?

Tags: f#

I have written a simple function that averages over parts of a sequence. First "column" has dates, second values. I have three variables to check on, start date (std) end date (edd) and businesshour (defined as 8-20 Mo-Fr = pob:string).

here is the funciton:

```
let internal aggrAvg data std edd pob =
data
|> Seq.averageBy (fun(a,b) -> 
    match a with 
    | r when isbetween r std edd ->
        match pob with
        |"Peak" when (ispeak a) -> b
        |"Offpeak" when (not (ispeak a)) -> b
        | _ -> b   
    | _ -> 0.0
    )
```

There are two issues with this:

1. Because pob is not part of the sequence the `match pob with` always fails
2. if date is not between std edd I want to skip and not assign 0.0 to the averageby

Any ideas how I can remedy these two issues? Thanks

**Update working solution based on Matthew's answer**

```
let internal aggrAvg data std edd pob =
    let ndata = data |> Seq.filter (fun (date, _) -> isbetween date std edd)
    match pob with
    | "Peak" -> ndata |> Seq.filter (fun (date, _) -> ispeak date) |> Seq.averageBy (fun (_, value) -> value)
    | "Offpeak" -> ndata |> Seq.filter (fun (date, _) -> not(ispeak date)) |> Seq.averageBy (fun (_, value) -> value)
    | _ -> ndata |> Seq.averageBy (fun (_, value) -> value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because pob is not part of the sequence the match pob with always
>   fails

It's always resulting in the value b anyway, what's the purpose in it?

To skip the dates not between your range you could filter the sequence before you do your average:

```
let internal aggrAvg data std edd pob =
    data
        |> Seq.filter (fun (date, _) -> isbetween date std edd)
        |> Seq.averageBy (fun (_, value) -> value)
```

Updated answer:

```
let internal aggrAvg data std edd pob =
    data 
        |> Seq.filter (fun (date, _) -> 
            let dateInRange = isbetween date std edd
            match pob with
            | "Peak" -> ispeak date && dateInRange
            | "Offpeak" -> not(ispeak date) && dateInRange
            | _ -> dateInRange)
        |> Seq.averageBy (fun (_, value) -> value)
```

Comment: thanks Matthew. So I have to go via Seq.Filter. Yes it results in b, but if pob is defined as Peak it only takes b from hrs 8-20 Mo - Fr. But I guess I can use filter here again

Comment: no problem, and yep you could extend the filter to also check the datetime is between the hours you want

Comment: I posted updated in my question. Would you do it like this or do I not have to define a new filtered tuple?

Comment: yeah, that's one way to do it, just updated my answer - might need a little changing around but gives you the general idea of how it could be done with a single filter

Comment: cool thank you. Do you think it makes a difference in terms of performance whether you use one or two filters?

Comment: it should be a bit more efficient using one filter as each filter will iterate over the sequence